# What is the regime of validity for linearized gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, coordinate-systems, dimensional-analysis, linearized-theory

A common formulation of the approximation is to assume the metric is give by
$$g_{\mu\nu}= \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu},$$ where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric and the components of $h_{\mu\nu}$ are small in some (global) coordinate system.
I have two main issues with the above formulation and would like to see if there are alternative ones. My issues are:

1. We assume a condition on the solution of Einstein equation, i.e. on the metric, but use it to solve the equation itself. One might consider is as an ansatz but I see no way of checking the solution. If we guess wrong we might never know.
2. The condition is explicitly coordinate dependent. On the one hand we can always find coordinates such that the metric is Minkowski at some point and $h_{\mu\nu} \propto L^2$, with $L$ the distance from that point. So the approximation is always valid in some small regime (for a chart) but [not globally](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/592099/). On the other hand it seems that people typically consider it to be valid for a global coordinate system.

Let me also add that often the approximating is justified by saying the curvature is small, or taking the [weak field limit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/764367/). To me this does not make sense since curvature is dimensionful so stating that it is small implies a scale. Alternatively one can point out that the curvature depends on the [derivative of $h$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/561213/).

It seems to me that other general consideration such as low density of matter or slow moving bodies cannot work either since the approximation can fail even for vacuum solutions. So any insight regarding when it is appropriate to use this approximation, and when it is not, would be quite helpful.

Comment: It depends on what you want to calculate with this metric. In linearized case, the inverse metric is just $g^{ab}=\eta^{ab}-h^{ab}$ . The higher order terms we are ignoring removes non-linearity. You can, for instance talk about GW with this approximation but then you can't account for gravitational mass loss

Comment: @KP99 I don't think it should depend, or in other words I want to know what *can* I calculate. You seem to suggest that the validity is determined case by case, but even then we would like to have some general criteria.